# Tensor manipulation in Keras

Tags: keras, tensor

I am trying to force an output on my Keras model. I want to take the largest output from the N-1 output weights of my model, and set the largest one to 1, and the remaining others to 0. So for instance if I have the folloeing output

W = [0.8, 0.2, 0.7, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2] it would be transformed to
W = [0.8, 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.].

To do so, here is what I have tried so far:

```
from classification_models.keras import Classifiers
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
import keras
import tensorflow as tf

ResNet18, preprocess_input = Classifiers.get('resnet18')
resnet = ResNet18((170, 170, 3), weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
headModel = keras.layers.pooling.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(3,3))(resnet.output)
headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
headModel = Dense(256, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
headModel = Dense(8, activation="sigmoid")(headModel)

# get the index of the value to be set to 1
highest_output_idx = tf.argsort(headModel[0][1:], direction='DESCENDING')[0] + 1

# set N-1 last values to 0
headModel[0][1:] = 0

# finally, set the highest index form the N-1 last values to 1
headModel[highest_output_idx] = 1
```

However, it gives me the following error:

````
TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment

```
````

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates, Tensor object does not support assignment. Instead you can use of numpy arrays.

For example if you have a tensor named `x`:

```
x = tf.constant([6,2,4,7,1], dtype=tf.float32)
```

You should first convert it to numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(x)
```

And then do the computations:

```
idx = np.argmax(x[1:]) # get index of maximum element after the first one
x[1:]=0                # set all to zero, except the first element
x[idx+1]=1             # set maximum to 1 (+1 because you removed first element from getting index)
```

And if you want a tensor you can again convert it to a tensor:

```
tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
```

Comment: Hi @Kaveh, thank you for your answer. Indeed that is what I tried doing, however it gives me the following error:'AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
'. I have been stuck around this ever since. Would you have a solution that would work with my headModel tensor? Thank you!

Comment: Are you using tensorflow 1 or 2?

Comment: Try ``np.array(x)`` instead of ``x.numpy()``. Don't forget to ``import numpy as np`` before statement. And the error you have mentioned in the last comment is due to tensorflow 1 or if you are using tensorflow 2 is due to using @tf.function.

Comment: ```np.array(headModel)``` does not work either, I get the following: ```NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (dense_1/Identity:0) to a numpy array.```.  I am using tensorflow 2. What do you mean when you say the @tf.function and how can I solve it if that's indeed what's causing my issues? thank you

Comment: Seems you have a hidden problem that could be from anywhere in your code. Please share more codes to your error be reproducible. Note: Try using tensorflow.keras instead of keras layers.

Comment: I just edited the code such that it is reproducible on your end. Let me know if you find how to solve this issue. In any case I highly appreciate it! thank you